# How to get Users associated to a Project in Rally

Tags: rally

Right now when we are fetching the project details using -https://Rally_Domain/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/Project_Object_id but Response doesn't have any info about list of users associated to that project

Comment: Project exposes TeamMembers and Editors collections which you can query.  Or is there another piece of info you're looking for?

Comment: We are trying to fetch List of all the users associated to a project irrespective of whether they have Project Admin, Editor or Viewer Permissions for that Rally Project. We have the Rally Project name. 
As you mentioned we can get Editors but Is it possible to get All the Users associated to that particular project?

Comment: I came across this API-https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/120971608896/Editors - which return Users with either Project Admin/Editors permissions but not the Viewers. 
Is there any way to get the users with Viewer Permissions  without querying all the users in Rally and then looking at project Permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can query the ProjectPermission endpoint scoped to that Project.

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/projectpermission?query=(Project = /project/120971608896)&fetch=User,Role
```

You can also include a filter by role if you're looking for just viewers.

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/projectpermission?query=((Project = /project/120971608896) AND (Role = "Project Viewer"))&fetch=User
```